# Vector Space Model Introduction

Tags: nlp, tf-idf, cosine-similarity, vsm

What are different types of [VSM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space_model) (vector space model)?

One which I know (as per wiki) is `tf-idf` (cosine similarity is used in this method, but its not a separate method). Which are other ways?

Also what are different dimensions of a word in a document (except frequency) being talked about in wiki?

Is there any hierarchy for VSMs?

P.S. Please correct me if I am wrong anywhere...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the paper [From Frequency to Meaning: Vector Space Models of Semantics](https://www.jair.org/media/2934/live-2934-4846-jair.pdf) - survey for Vector space models of semantics.
For your particular question about frequency, see sections 4.2 and 4.3: in short, one uses tf-idf, PMI, PPM with further smoothing (mainly by some variations of SVD).

But, since this survey is dated by 2010, there is no mention of deep learning-based VSM, see [the paper](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/5021-distributed-representations-of-words-and-phrases-and-their-compositionality.pdf).